# C#: generic function that return element from collection based on condition

Tags: c#, collections, func

So i have this `function` that return element from `collection` based on `condition`

```
public static T Search<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> filter)
{
    return source.FirstOrDefault(filter);
}
```

And i want to convert this to return all the `elements` form my `collection` that mach my `condition`.

so instead of change the function signature to `public static IEnumerable<T> Search<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> filter)`

What i need to changed inside my function ?

Comment: Does `return source.Where(filter);` work?

Comment: Just use the `First()`, `Where()` directly, they are standard in C#, no need to wrap them inside another `Search()` function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Where` instead of `FirstOrDefault`

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Search<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> filter)
{
    return source.Where(filter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Where method instead of FirstOrDefault